# error while installing baruta through pip

Tags: machine-learning, installation, pip

I have windows 11 OS and python 3.10.9 installed. Installing baruta package through pip gave following error:
Installing collected packages: scikit-learn, boruta
ERROR: Could not install packages due to an OSError: [WinError 5] Access is denied: 'C:\Users\Gunak\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\Lib\site-packages\sklearn\.libs\msvcp140.dll'
Consider using the `--user` option or check the permissions.
the same can be seen in the below image.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VySHM.png)

Please help me out with this issue, and let me know how can I install it with out any errors and also please give some information on what the error represent .

Thanks in advance.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpip%5D+Could+not+install+packages+due+to+an+OSError%3A+WinError+5+Access+is+denied

Answer (score 1):

You can try `pip install --user ...` first or try to do it with admin.

It may because that file is read-only.

Comment: i tried that option also but didnt work